# How large are the planets in Star Wars: The Old Republic?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

How large are the planets in Bioware's Star Wars MMORPG? How do they compare to the continents in World of Warcraft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since TOR is unreleased yet, no one can honestly answer this question. However with everything Bioware has shown so far, TOR *appears* to mimic or improve (hopefully) upon WoW in many aspects, such as companion characters to speed up preparing raid parties.

Furthermore in Star Wars Galaxies, the planets where quite large and offering plenty of exploration (if that is what you are looking for). Bioware is also focused on story, so I doubt a planet will be superficially large with large expanses of empty ground for size sake.

In terms of total land mass, my gut feeling is TOR will be comparable, if not large, than WoW. Don't forget that TOR will include space combat, therefore space zones must be included too.

[TOR Forum: A little perspective on planet size](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=153557)

Comment: Having played the beta, I would say the size of the planets would be hard to compare to continents of WoW...

I would say the planets are about the size of 3-4 zones of WoW... I would compare it to Elwynn Forest-Westfall-RedridgeMountains-Duskwoods, the 4 start zones of the humans. It would be about that size.

Comment: The game's now out (apparently)